# Why java lang nosuchmethoderror at runtime resolved when changed from Wrapper class to primitive

Tags: java, oop, wrapper, primitive, nosuchmethoderror

I have face issue NoSuchMethodError even though that method is in my jar file.
**Server** : Tomcat 7
**Java Version :** 1.6.0_43

**Exception : `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.Person.setPersonId(J)V`**

```
long l1 = 1234;
Person p = new Person();
p.setPersonId(l1);
```

**NoSuchMethodError** come while

```
class Person {  
Long personId;
public Long getPersonId() {
    return personId;
}
public void setPersonId(Long personId) {
    this.personId = personId;
}   
}
```

*NoSuchMethodError resolved when change Wrapper to primitive*

```
class Person {
long personId;
public long getPersonId() {
    return personId;
}
public void setPersonId(long personId) {
    this.personId = personId;
}
}
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace please.

Comment: Your program compiles and runs fine - the problem is not in what you have shown so far...

Comment: Some code in the background appears to be using reflection. And `Class.getMethod` does no boxing magic to find methods with "compatible" parameter types.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you've recompiled `Person` but not recompiled the code using it.

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine in principle either way. Most likely there is some mismatch between the code the compiler sees and the code used at runtime.

`setPersonId(Long personId)` and `setPersonId(long personId)` are different methods. If the expected one isn't present, you will get NoSuchMethodError, not something like NotThatMethodDidYouMeanThisOneInsteadError.

[Autoboxing](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/autoboxing.html) was added in Java 1.5, so a less likely possibility is there is some mismatch in configuration as to what language version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
long l1 = 1234;    here you have declared primitive long
Person p = new Person();
p.setPersonId(l1); in this statement its returning l1 primitive long not Long
```

and `public Long getPersonId()` in your method return type is Long. Thats why its giving an error.

Comment: There is `autoboxing` in Java 6 so this is possible to convert from long to Long.

Comment: yes , You are absolutely right but in your case it not returning Long. `Autoboxing ` should work here as java concept.

Answer (score -1):

Use primitive `long`, instead of wrapper `Long`.

Comment: I only asking **why** , try to find out why this happend

Comment: This answer just restates information in the question, you need to explain the reason.